# Авторизация в nginx через ntlm по токенам AD (SSO)

Tags: linux, nginx, active-directory, kerberos, ntlm

Как сделать сквозную авторизацию на веб сервисе по кнопке без ввода логина и пароля пользователя AD используя токен полученный от AD при авторизации на компьютере?

Пример: пользователь заходит в доменную учётку, запускает браузер и переходит по ссылке веб приложения развёрнутого на linux сервере через nginx. В приложение есть либо кнопка "авторизоваться", либо авторизация проходит автоматически. При этом приложение, получает от AD сервера данные связанные с этой учетной записью (группы, права, etc...)
P.S. nginx пересобрал с модулем spnego-http-auth-nginx-module, и хотелось бы обойтись без kerberos и ввода линукс сервера в домен.

Comment: Не знаю, чем вас не устроил kerberos. Как по мне - так это самый отличный вариант. У меня через kerberos работает squid и apache. Никакие "ввод линукс в домен" я не делал. Сервису эта процедура не нужна, в домене должен быть клиент.

Comment: И второй вопрос. Что вы подразумеваете под словом "авторизация"? Если это то, что юзеру не надо/надо вводить логин-пароль, то это - **аутентификация**. А вот _При этом приложение, получает от AD сервера данные связанные с этой учетной записью (группы, права, etc...)_  больше похоже на авторизацию, и является другим, отличным от аутентификации, процессом.

Comment: под авторизацией я понимаю аутентификацию и авторизацию. Пользователь не должен вводить логинов/паролей, а сервис на линуксе должен по токену понять что это за пользователь и в каких группах он состоит. Как у вас это настроено с керберосом без ввода линукс сервера в домен?

Comment: Ещё вносит смуту статья на хабре, https://habr.com/ru/company/dataart/blog/262817/ там утверждается что керберосу обязательно нужно быть в домене как и клиенту

Comment: В свое время я за основу брал вот эту [статью](http://xgu.ru/wiki/Squid,_Kerberos_%D0%B8_LDAP). Аналогичным образом я настраивал Apache. Если в статьях про kerberos люди пишут о _вводе в домен_, то скорее всего они накручивают на сервере еще какой-нибудь winbind. `... сервис на линуксе должен по токену понять что это за пользователь и **в каких группах он состоит** ` - разве по токену можно определить принадлежность к группам? Я про это ничего не знаю, и сомневаюсь, что это возможно. Поделитесь плиз инфой по этому поводу.

Comment: честно говоря пока не могу сказать. знаю что IIS может получать эту информацию, соответственно предполагаю что и linux сможет получить эту инфу через kerberos или ntlm

Comment: Понятно. Всё не так, потому что вы не разделяете процессы "аутентификации" и "авторизации". **Аутентификация** - это kerberos, ntlm, basic. **Авторизация** - это, например, ldap запрос к AD (Ldap серверу), для определения принадлежности к группе. В статье про squid, что я давал ссылку, эти процессы как раз отдельно описаны. С Апачем будет тоже самое, с IIS аналогично. Процесс авторизации (поиска принадлежности юзера к группе), на мой взгляд, лучше делать на стороне веб-приложения, а не средствами веб-сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось реализовать без ввода linux сервера в домен. На linux пересобирали nginx с модулем *spnego-http-auth-nginx-module-master*, поставили *krb5-user*. На вин сервере добавили linux сервер как службу и в общем то теперь по протоколу ldap linux получает списки групп пользователя и другую инфу из AD.

Полезная ссылка по LDAP:

http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2018/05/14/convertaciya-atributa-useraccountcontrol-v-ad/